# How to override a django app's model and use the same db table?

Tags: database, django, django-models

I want to override an existing model and use a different manager, while keeping the same db table so I can query the same data using different managers in different places.

My code as following:

MyTagging/models.py

```
from tagging.models import Tag as tagging_tag, TagManager as tagging_tagmanager
class TagManager(tagging_tagmanager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(TagManager,self).get_query_set().filter(site=settings.SITE_ID)

class Tag(tagging_tag):
    #id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    objects=TagManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table="tagging_tag"
```

But if I sql it the code is going to be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Tagging_local_tag" (
    "tag_ptr_id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES "tagging_tag" ("id")
)
;
```

The `tag_ptr_id` field is causing problems here, it's trying to create a new table and reference the original one.

Is there any way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) like this:

```
class Tag(tagging_tag):
    #id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    objects=TagManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Comment: Thanks! Just figured it out :)